# PHP echo short tag <?= ?> that also has echo keyword in it

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In a Wordpress website with some fairly extensive customization by the company that designed and implemented it for us, I'm finding a few different implementations of PHP echo statements (all of which are functionally equivalent, see the not-a-duplicate question), and I'm trying to figure out if there are valid differences between them, or if the guy doing the coding was just inconsistent. 
These will be taken a little out of context, but are in the exact same file only a few lines apart. Let me know if you need more of the surrounding code to figure it out.

Example 1 - full PHP `<?php echo ?>` tag. Because its being generated inside an img src tag? (edited the closing tag in my question)

```
<div class="heroImage">
    <div class="entry-featured mtn">
        <img src="<?php echo $himageurl; ?>"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example 2 - `<? echo $variable ?>` (is it overkill to use short echo tag AND echo?)

```
<div  class="x-column x-sm x-1-1" style="padding: 0px;" >
    <h1  class="h-custom-headline cs-ta-center subpageTitle h1" >
        <span><? echo get_the_title(); ?></span>    
    </h1>
        <span><? echo $term_meta['subtitle'][0]; ?></span>
</div>
```

Example 3 - Never mind. I couldn't find a good example of  being used by itself.

`<? $something ?>`

So, the basic question: **is this an example of good usage of various PHP echo techniques in different situations that I can/should be learning from? Or is this just inconsistency in implementation, and I should really favor one over the other in my own coding?** (I know this shades into opinions, and if so, let me know. I'm more concerned that there's a right/wrong answer and I don't know which yet.)

Comment: I didn't think it was legal syntax

Comment: `<?php echo />` is not in the code, right? `<img src="<?php echo $himageurl; ?>"/>` is correct because the only PHP is between the `<?php` and `?>`. The `/>` after the `?>` is closing the open `img` element.

Comment: `<?` Was allowed in some version of PHP or other `<?php` is standard

Comment: `<?` isn't a short-echo, its the short-open-tag and it's off by default in later php-versions, i'd recomment not using it at all.

Comment: @RiggsFolly PHP 5.4 introduced them (and Zend went nuts using them). Suddenly `<?= ?>` was back in vogue

Comment: @Machavity in no way does that post represent a duplicate. I'm aware both types of coding are possible and allowable, thanks. REad that post repeatedly before posting. I'm asking specifically about mixing them in the exact same codebase and if there are times to use one over the other OR if it's just coder inconsistency.

Comment: @DustinKreidler The point of the duplicate is that they are programmatically equivalent. Asking when to use one over the other is opinion based, and thus off-topic

Comment: @Machavity overall, sure, but in the exact same file separated by 7 lines?

Comment: @DustinKreidler It's worth noting that this is Wordpress we're talking about. It's been cobbled together over the years and still aims to work with PHP 5.2. I don't think they're aiming for consistency.

Comment: @Machavity duly noted! LOL... that was actually more or less my response to tkausl's answer: I'm nowhere NEAR using a PHP version where this becomes a problem!

Comment: @tkausl or machavity, worth doing some speedy find and replace of "<? " with "<?= " just to keep everything up to date? Or am I still missing something about the difference between "<?" and "<?=" ?

Comment: `<?=` is the same as `<?php echo `; `<?` is the same as `<?php`; that's the difference.

Comment: @DustinKreidler My advice is to pick one and be consistent. Mixing and matching syntax is to invite confusion.

Comment: Short echo (`<?=`) is just nice to use inside html and allowed in almost all php installs, short open (`<?`) is, opinionated, bad practice and very often not allowed in php installs.

Comment: We're all wrong (except for @RiggsFolly): https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#no-shorthand-php-tags

In answer to my actual question: it was just inconsistent application of tags AND, at least in Wordpress, a non-recommended usage of them. Anyone want to post that as an actual answer, since I can't? (Because I asked the question, or because of the (sorry, still erroneous) "dupe" marking?)